# Electron webview preload log DOM

Tags: javascript, html, webview, electron

I am using a webview in my index.html file in my Electron program. The webview has a preloader and I simply want to be able to manipulate the DOM of the webview (not index.html).

I have this code in my preloader. But the console.log outputs the **document of index.html** and not the document of the webview. How can I output the contents of the **webview**?

preload.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  console.log(document);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The webview will emit `console-message` events every time it console.logs something, you just have to listen to them. See docs for [webview-tag](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#event-console-message):

```
const webview = document.querySelector('webview')
webview.addEventListener('console-message', (e) => {
  console.log('Guest page logged a message:', e.message)
})
```